# Problemas para actualizar a node 14.16.0

Tags: python-3.x, nodejs, jupyter

En el entorno base de mi ordenador, tengo instalada la versión 6.14.11 de nodejs.
Al intentar instalar paquetes con jupyter-lab, el sistema me advierte de que tengo que tener instalada una versión nodejs >= 12.0 . Para cambiar la versión instalada, he seguido los siguientes pasos.

```
(base) enri@enri-260-p100ns:~$ sudo npm -v
6.14.11
(base) enri@enri-260-p100ns:~$ sudo n 14.16.0
   installed : v14.16.0 (with npm 6.14.11)
(base) enri@enri-260-p100ns:~$ sudo npm -v
6.14.11
```

Jupyter, me sigue dando el mismo error

Pruebo con `conda install nodejs -c conda-forge --repodata-fn=repodata.json` que, teóricamente debería instalar versione >13, pero la versión instalada, no me cambia.

```
(base) enri@enri-260-p100ns:~$ sudo npm -v
[sudo] contraseña para enri:         
6.14.11
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Agradeceré ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No soy experto en linux ni mucho menos en Node pero espero ayudarte.

Primero te recomendaria limpiar el cache, esto normalmente no es necesario pero ya que estas atravesando errores quizas pueda servir.

Para limpiar el cache te dejo esta linea:

```
~$ sudo npm cache clean -f
```

Ahora bien, te dejo los pasos a seguir, estos me funcionaron a mi en su momento:

Debes descargar NVM(Node Version Manager) utilizando wget; en el caso de no estar seguro de utilizar wget realiza el siguiente comando: `sudo apt install wget`

Luego procede a realizar este comando: `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash`

Para que el NVM se utilice desde el perfil de bash en tu usuario, realiza el este comando: `source ~/.profile`

Una vez listo, puedes utilizar NVM y mostrar las versiones de Node.js para instalar: `nvm ls-remote`

Allí puedes escoger el que quieras. Para una mejor estabilidad y soporte es recomendable la versión 10.15.1. Para eso debes ejecutar este comando: `nvm install 10.15.1`

Para asegurarte de que está instalado el Node.js, ejecuta este comando: `node -v`.

PD: Por experiencia personal, despues de instalar el nvm te recomiendo reiniciar la terminal.